# How would i go about making a VB application that creates an exe file?

Tags: .net, vb.net

there is something I discovered a while ago but have never been able to figure out. I was browsing the internet and I came across a virus maker. I downloaded it (out of curiosity of course) and read the README.txt file, the file said that this software was created in visual basic/vb.net. Well what suprised me was when you opened the application you could choose many things that you want your virus to do, then you could click create and it saved an .exe file to a chosen location. To my suprise it worked, it actually created an exe file. How would i go about making an exe file from within an application like that? I googled it but nothing came up!

Comment: The term you are looking for is called [`CodeDOM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler(v=vs.110).aspx).  A NET app can create a source file and compile to to an assembly either on disk or in memory.  Very useful for certain kinds of dynamic operations, though not a beginner topic.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line, *technically* speaking, is that:  "yes, Visual Basic *can* generate an .EXE file."

*"Well, sort of ..."*

What the dot-Net flavor of Visual Basic will *actually* generate is a file of dot-Net bytecodes, prefixed by a small stub-routine that loads and executes the dot-Net interpreter DLL, which is presumed to exist.

The writers of this nefarious piece of software simply used those ordinary facilities.  And *no,* I certainly don't need to take a look at it . . .

Comment: VB.Net code is not interpreted.  It is JIT compiled into native machine code and then executed.

Comment: Entirely true ... technically speaking ... but the "JIT compiled" step is *(for my purposes, at least)* functionally equivalent to "interpretation."  Although the exact path taken between point-A and point-B is not strictly as I described it, the essential notion is that "a path *is taken.*"